# Relationship between Registrar and DNS Server

Tags: dns, registrar

I don't quite get how registrar and DNS server interact. 
What happen when I enter `mydomain111.org` (assuming that i bought it through name cheap and point the DNS server to DO). Is it something like:

Registrar (namecheap) > DNS Server (Digital Ocean) > Mapped Server Record?

I have a application server running in our intranet, I'm thinking of how to access it via `mydomain111.org` instead of `192.168.1.15:8090`

Comment: registrars enter your domain in the Domain Name Registry (hence the clever name) for the top-level domain your domain exists in (.com, .gov, .edu, etc ). Then you can either host a publicly accessible DNS server  yourself, and define a zone within it containing your hosts, or you can often have the registrar host the zone themselves. The registrar will import your zone and include it in a periodic zone transfer up to the tld registry. ISPs DNS servers pull a zone transfer from the tld servers periodically, and thats how other servers learn about the addresses you register.

Comment: The comment by @FrankThomas is correct in how the DNS system works; using that, if you want to map `whatever.com` to an INTRAnet server (e.g. `192.168.1.15`), you'll need to host your own DNS server on your network. Further, if you want port `8090` to be the port the server hosts the site on, you'll need to add a rule on the server to look for requests to `whatever.com` to `192.168.1.15:8090` ..